# Scroll and zoom in morris chart data collapsed

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, morris.js

[image]I have used morris js chart in yii2, I have a problem when data range goes too high, the lower data range gets collapsed, is there any way to see it clearly? Also, want to show data of entire week to it needs to scroll up in the x-axis.

```
function callpathgraphjs() {
    "use strict";
    var completed = $('#completed_graph').attr('completed_data');
    var completed_values = JSON.parse('[' + completed + ']');

    Morris.Line({
        axes: 'x',
        element: 'completed-chart',
        data: completed_values,
        xkey: ['inserted_at'],
        ykeys: ['tioc_inbound_calls', 'tioc_outbound_calls','tioc_total_current_calls','tioc_max_call_paths'],
        lineColors: ['#FFA233', '#B30FDC','#0000FF','#FF0000'],
        labels: ['Inbound Calls', 'Outbound Calls','Total Calls','Max CallPaths'],
        resize: true,
        xLabelAngle: 60,
        grid:true,
        pointSize: 4,
        lineWidth: 2,
        yLabels:"5min",
        parseTime:false,
        xLabelMargin: 50,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to display data with big gaps is to use a logarithmic scale. To do that, you'll have to extend Morris because there's no build-in parameter.

Please try the following snippet. I extended Morris with an `yLogScale`parameter and provided two buttons to set it on and off. I also set the `padding` parameter to 80 to display the x labels completely.

```js
(function () {
    var $, MyMorris;

    MyMorris = window.MyMorris = {};
    $ = jQuery;

    MyMorris = Object.create(Morris);

    MyMorris.Grid.prototype.gridDefaults["yLogScale"] = false;

    MyMorris.Grid.prototype.transY = function (y) {
        if (!this.options.horizontal) {
            if (this.options.yLogScale) {
                return this.bottom - (this.height * Math.log((y + 1) - this.ymin) / Math.log(this.ymax / (this.ymin + 1)));
            } else {
                return this.bottom - (y - this.ymin) * this.dy;
            }
        } else {
            return this.left + (y - this.ymin) * this.dy;
        }
    };
}).call(this);

var MorrisLine = null;
var data = [
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-20 12:18', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-20 12:23', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-20 12:28', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-21 06:21', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-21 07:21', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-22 07:21', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-22 07:21', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-23 06:30', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-21 06:35', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-21 06:40', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 50 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-21 06:45', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 600, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 800, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 1200, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 1800 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-21 06:50', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 29, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 20, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 49, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 1800 },
    { 'inserted_at': '2019-11-21 06:55', 'tioc_inbound_calls': 0, 'tioc_outbound_calls': 0, 'tioc_total_current_calls': 0, 'tioc_max_call_paths': 0 }
];

MorrisLine = Morris.Line({
    axes: 'x',
    element: 'completed-chart',
    data: data,
    xkey: ['inserted_at'],
    ykeys: ['tioc_inbound_calls', 'tioc_outbound_calls', 'tioc_total_current_calls', 'tioc_max_call_paths'],
    lineColors: ['#FFA233', '#B30FDC', '#0000FF', '#FF0000'],
    labels: ['Inbound Calls', 'Outbound Calls', 'Total Calls', 'Max CallPaths'],
    yLogScale: false,
    resize: true,
    xLabelAngle: 60,
    grid: true,
    pointSize: 4,
    lineWidth: 2,
    yLabels: "5min",
    parseTime: false,
    padding: 80,
    xLabelMargin: 50
});

$(".button").on("click", function () {
    $(".button").removeClass("on");
    $(this).addClass("on");
});

function setYLogScale(status) {
    MorrisLine.options["yLogScale"] = status;
    MorrisLine.setData(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  body { font-family: Arial; }
  .button {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .on { background-color: lightblue; }
</style>

<div class="button" onclick="setYLogScale(true);">yLogScale ON</div>
<div class="button" onclick="setYLogScale(false);">yLogScale OFF</div>
<div id="completed-chart"></div>
```